# How to add a minute in Hue HIVE DB

Tags: sql, hive, date-formatting, dateadd

I need to add a minute in my SQL query which i was written in HIVE DB.

```
Select date_need from myschema.table order by date_need
```

If i am giving as AS,`` to use alias.It was not accepting.I need to add a minute.
For example , date_need has **2021-05-09 03:30:24**  and  i need to display as **2021-05-09 03:31:24**
date_need declared as string type in query

Answer (score 0):

use `+INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`.

```
Select cast(date_need as timestamp)+INTERVAL '1' MINUTE as date_need from myschema.table order by 1
```